# Can't load R library on server using Rscript command

Tags: r, gplots

I'm calling from perl-cgi using

`my $call = qx(Rscript tcga_analysis.R $bg_name $ctr_name $set $user);`

when I use `Rscript myRscript.R` from unix on a server it works but from perl I can't seem to be able to load any package. I get the following error (from Apache log):

`Error in library(gplots) : there is no package called 'gplots'`

using .libPaths():

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/sbattaglia/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

which shows my personal library in the home folder.

I tried using

```
library(gplots, lib.loc="/home/sbattaglia/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1")
```

but I get a `lib.loc error` saying that there is no library trees in there .
I even created an `.Rprofile` file in the working directory containing the path to the library, but no success. I also tried to add `pos=1` but with no success...

however, if I open R and call `library(gplots)` it works

I need to have it working calling Rscript from perl because it's part of an analysis pipeline that uses a web interface -> perl-cgi -> R to analyze some data!

thanks :)

Comment: Is the cgi script run by a different user, maybe apache? Possibly a permission issue.

Comment: I am the owner of the var/www/html folder containing both R and perl cgi scripts

Comment: It's the permissions of the R libraries that seem to be a problem. Try `chmod -R a+r /home/sbattaglia/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1`, i.e. make everything readable to anyone.

Comment: @flodel just tried, same error on the log: `Error in library(gplots) : there is no package called 'gplots'`

Comment: Can you please provide the output of running `ls -ld /home/sbattaglia/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/gplots` as yourself?

Comment: output is `drwxrwxr-x. 8 sbattaglia sbattaglia 4096 Sep  6 11:39 /home/sbattaglia/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/gplots` ...which at my eyes says that permissions shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60754/discussion-between-flodel-and-trirook).

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna post the answer that came up in the chat with @floded.

basically the libraries were in a folder on the server that were not visible to Apache. 
I re-downloaded the packages I needed in the location where the .R and .cgi files were, specified `library(gplots, lib.loc="correctPathToLibrary")` and it worked :)